# How to expand the height of child div's to fit parent div, in a hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is the structure of my layout. The code for it is posted in the end of this question. What I want is that

1. The wrapper div `entire-page` `height` should not exceed the *height of the browser window without the scroll bar*. **I do not want a scroll-bar in the parent window.**
2. The `left-div` and `right-div` `heigh`t should be equal to the `height` of their `parent div`. Their `parent div` should fit the `height` of its `parent div` and *so on*, until the effect to be seen is that the *`left-div` and the `right-div` have spanned all the space available to them* "heightwise"
3. The `left-div` and the `right-div` should be such that if their contents increase their `height`, **a `scroll-bar` should show**, but if the contents are smaller than their height, it should not show *any trace* of `scroll-bar`.

*I have searched about it a lot and tried various things but nothing helped me get the exact desired effect.*

**So how can I go about it?**

**PROBLEMATIC LAYOUT :**
[image]

**WHAT I WANT :**

[image]

**CODE :**

```
<div id="entire-page" style="padding-top: 72px; overflow: hidden; background-color: grey; height: 100vh;" >         
    <div id="parent-div" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; ">            
        <div id="information-bar" style=" border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: grey; border-bottom-width: 1px; font-family: sans-serif; color: #000029; padding:5px; ">                
            <p> I am the information bar... </p>                
        </div>            
        <div id="main-content-wrapper" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width:100%; height:100%; background-color: greenyellow;">                
            <div id="left-div" style="; width: 49.9%; display:block; float:left; font-family: sans-serif; border-right-color:grey; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; position:absolute; height: 100%; left:0; background-color: blueviolet;">
                <p style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:25px; ">
                    A , concluded that city dwellers are on average more generous than residents of rural areas.A survey of charitable 
                    giving in the state found that the average dollarnt contributed by residents of rural 
                    areas. The survey’s creators, an urban-promotion group known as Live in the City, concluded that city 
                    dwellers are on average more generous than residents of rural areas.
                </p>

            </div>                 
            <div id="right-div" style="width:50%; display:block; float:right; font-family: sans-serif; background-color: brown;">                     
                <p style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:25px; " >
                    by residents of rural areas. The survey’s creators, an urban-promotion group known as Live in the City, 
                    concluded that city dwellers are on average more generous thidents of urban areas to 
                    programs for the homeless was $15 greater than the amount contributed by residents of rural areas. 
                    The survey’s creators, an urban-promotion group known as Live in the City, concluded that city dwellers 
                    are on average more generous than residents of rural areas.
                </p>                    
            </div>                
        </div>                
    </div> 
</div>
```

The header and footer will be included from an external file.

---

EDIT:-

This is strange. Following is the result of writing an html file and compiling it from netbeans. While in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/U7PhY/2/), it works!

[image]

Comment: what about set the height to 100% for right-div and left-div?

Comment: That does not work. That only sets the height to fit the components. I tried that anyway and it did not work. @user3003216

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="entire-page" style="padding-top: 72px; overflow: hidden; background-color: grey; height: 100vh;" >
```

remove height: 100vh; try with height:100% or if not remove this attribute from the style....
If it is not working, make a fiddle.

Comment: I tried that over and over and over again? It does not help. `Height:100%` fits it to its contents, not the parent!

Comment: So finally, is it working with height attribute or without height attribute......
I made a fiddle in that I removed height attribute and it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="parent-div" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; ">

    <div id="information-bar" style=" border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: grey; border-bottom-width: 1px; font-family: 
         sans-serif; color: #000029; padding:5px; ">

        <p> I am the information bar... </p>

    </div>

    <div id="main-content-wrapper" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width:100%; height:100%; background-color: greenyellow;">

        <div id="left-div" style="height=100%; width: 49.9%; display:block; float:left; font-family: sans-serif; 
              border-right-color:grey; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; position:absolute; height: 100%; left:0; background-color: blueviolet;">

             <p style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:25px; ">A , concluded 
                 that city dwellers are on average more generous than residents of rural areas.A survey of charitable 
                 giving in the state found that the average dollarnt contributed by residents of rural 
                 areas. The survey’s creators, an urban-promotion group known as Live in the City, concluded that city 
                 dwellers are on average more generous than residents of rural areas.</p>

        </div>

         <div id="right-div" style="height:100%; width:50%; display:block; float:right; font-family: sans-serif; background-color: brown;">

            <p style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:25px; " >by 
                 residents of rural areas. The survey’s creators, an urban-promotion group known as Live in the City, 
                 concluded that city dwellers are on average more generous thidents of urban areas to 
                 programs for the homeless was $15 greater than the amount contributed by residents of rural areas. 
                 The survey’s creators, an urban-promotion group known as Live in the City, concluded that city dwellers 
                 are on average more generous than residents of rural areas.</p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

K